# a single ColorRamp palette yields different color schemes in two plotly scatterplots

Tags: r, plotly

As the title says, a single ColorRamp palette when used in two different scetterplots built by plotly, gives two slightly differently looking (note the middle part) colorbars even though the upper and the lower bounds of corresponding data sets are manually set to be identical in both plots.

I'd like to make the plots visually comparable, and for that I'd obviously have to have identical colorbars. Is there a way to do that?

Here's the code:

```
myxaxis <- list(range = c(16, 44), dtick=2, gridwidth = 1, title = "Length of carbon chain") #setting the visible area of x axis
myyaxis <- list(range = c(0, 8), gridwidth = 1, title = "No. of double bonds") #setting the visible area of y axis
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(c('green', 'red', 'black'))(n = 100) #creating an RColorBrewer palette

ch_new1 <- cbind.data.frame(c('PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'PA', 'upper bound', 'lower bound'), c(4.571087, 6.522441, 6.522441, 5.081869, 4.471815, 5.744834, 7.329796, 5.472866, 5.744834, 1, 1), c(10.52337, 16.75454, 16.0976, 16.47356, 18.94973, 17.46351, 10.97607, 18.11186, 11.64033, 0.2085327, 71.18021), c(32, 34, 34, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 38, 100, 100), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 100, 100), c(0.4128963, 16.68394, 26.52718, 23.50851, 16.02339, 3.971546, 6.854153, 3.24342, 2.774968, 1, 1)) #the first dataset
colnames(ch_new1) <- c('Species', 'log_inversed_pval','fold_difference', 'N_of_carbons','N_of_double_bonds', 'rel_abund')
d <- plot_ly(ch_new1, x=~N_of_carbons, y=~N_of_double_bonds, text = ~paste('Percent of total', Species, '=', round(rel_abund, 0)), size=~rel_abund, color=~fold_difference, colors = mycolors)%>% #producing the scatter plot
  layout(
    xaxis = myxaxis,
    yaxis = myyaxis,
    title = paste('PA', '2b')
  )%>%
  colorbar(title="Fold difference", ypad=20)
export(d)

ch_new2 <- cbind.data.frame(c('LPC', 'LPC', 'LPC', 'lower limit', 'upper limit'), c(7.329796, 7.329796, 5.081869, 1, 1), c(2.952345, 5.042931, 3.700331, 0.2085327, 71.18021), c(18, 20, 22, 100, 100), c(0, 3, 5, 100, 100), c(82.87528, 13.56943, 3.555281, 1, 1)) #the second dataset
colnames(ch_new2) <- c('Species', 'log_inversed_pval','fold_difference', 'N_of_carbons','N_of_double_bonds', 'rel_abund')
d <- plot_ly(ch_new2, x=~N_of_carbons, y=~N_of_double_bonds, text = ~paste('Percent of total', Species, '=', round(rel_abund, 0)), size=~rel_abund, color=~fold_difference, colors = mycolors)%>% #creating the second scatterplot
  layout(
    xaxis = myxaxis,
    yaxis = myyaxis,
    title = paste(unique(ch$Species)[i], fraction)
  )%>%
  colorbar(title="Fold difference", ypad=20)
export(d)
```

[chart #1 with bright red middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb1YH.png)

[chart #2 with dim red middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ApJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem on my own.

Turns out that by adding one or several "anchoring" dummy points placed beyond the margins of the plot (so they are not shown) helps to make the plot colorbars almost identical.

The initial dataset

> ch_new1 <- cbind.data.frame(c(...)) #the first dataset

should be appended with anchoring dummy points:

> ch_new1 <- cbind.data.frame(c(...)) #the first dataset
>
> ch_new1 <- rbind(ch_new, list('middle anchor point', 1, 50, 100, 100, 1))
>
> ch_new1 <- rbind(ch_new, list('quarter anchor point', 1, 25, 100, 100, 1))

**tl;dr** anchor the variable responsible for colorbar to multiple reference points (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, ...)